# file object path in python

Tags: python-2.7, csv, object, path

This is my piece of code :-

```
import urllib2
import re
from lxml import html
from random import randint
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import requests, csv, time, urllib2, os, ast, datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
from collections import OrderedDict
import tkFileDialog, os
```

I set csvfile variable to create a file object here -

```
csvfile = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".csv")
```

When i am using this :-

```
with open (csvfile,'ab') as export:
    fieldnames = ['link', 'Emails', 'Emails1']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(export, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
```

I am getting an error :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ssamant\Desktop\Testing\get_all_links.py", line 32, in <module>
    with open (csvfile,'ab') as export:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

It says file object found , not path or string , How can get the csvfile (path) so that i can use the same in my csv function. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a file object, you need to pass a string which you can get using the `name` attribute:

```
with open (csvfile.name,'ab') as export:
    fieldnames = ['link', 'Emails', 'Emails1']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(export, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
```

Example a file name `foo`:

```
In [1]: from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfile   
In [2]: csvfile = asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".csv")    
In [3]: csvfile.name
Out[3]: '/home/padraic/foo.csv'
```

You can also just pass the file object directly to `csv.DictWriter`:

```
    fieldnames = ['link', 'Emails', 'Emails1']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
```